# How to find index of cell value in range without using an embedded IF Statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please see the photo below. I'd like to find which Number in row 3, is affiliated with the first number higher than the number in cell `B1`. As you can see below, the first number higher than `11.2` is `11.59`. The desired output is the number affiliated with `11.59` in row 3, which is `4`.

Is there a way to do this without a 10 times embedded IF statement and still use inbuilt Excel formulas. I'd prefer not to use VBA for this one as well.

[image]

Comment: `MATCH()` or `LOOKUP()`  can do this. Also it's columns have letters, rows have numbers =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the formula for cell E1:

```
    =OFFSET(INDEX(B5:K5,MATCH(TRUE,B5:K5>B1,0)),-2,0)
```

This is an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter).

[image]

Comment: Or rather: `=INDEX(B3:K3,MATCH(TRUE,B5:K5>B1,0))`

Comment: Provided that the numbers are in order small to large. Otherwise you need to best a large function in it.